# SQL Combine data from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to combine two tables in SQL?

Suppose we have table called books

```
book_id    author_id       name
_______    _________       _____________
1          2               XYZ
2          1               ABC
```

And we have table called authors

```
author_id        firstname        surname
___________      ____________     ___________
1                Alex             Woodman
2                Steve            Bush
```

I want to combine books and authors in select query:

```
book_id       author_id     name          author_name
_________     __________    __________    ______________
1             2             XYZ           Steve Bush
2             1             ABC           Alex Woodman
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) clause to merge the two tables and use the [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to concatenate name and surname of the author:

```
SELECT 
    b.book_id, 
    a.author_id, 
    b.name, 
    CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.surname) AS author_name
FROM 
    books b 
JOIN 
    author a ON b.author_id = a.author_id
```